# How to customize default pagination in laravel 8?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pagination

I'm building an application where some page needs pagination. I already made a design for my application's pagination. But how can I use that with laravel paginate?

I did this for paginate in the controller

```
 $products= Products::paginate(9);
```

In my blade, this is my desired HTML for pagination

```
          <div class="row pt-3 pb-5">
            <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-end">
                <div class="pagination-btn-box">
                    <button class="active-pagination-btn">1</button>
                    <button>2</button>
                    <button>3</button>
                    <button>4</button>
                    <button>5</button>
                    <button>...</button>
                    <button>Next</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Now, How can I implement this with laravel for paginating?

Comment: As in you want to customise the pagination links?

Comment: I want to customize the default pagination design and links

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view

Comment: @ihprince. posted an answer to create custom view .It might help you to solve a bit

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In controller return view

```
return view('blade file name',compact('products'))
```

in blade do like below

```
<div class="container">
    @foreach ($products as $product)
        {{ $product->fieldname}}
    @endforeach
</div>

{{ $products->links() }}
```

`$products->links()` will generate default pagination.

if you want to customize pagination template then run following command

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination
```

this will generate folder in views/vendor/pagination

`default.blad.php` look like below

```
@if ($paginator->hasPages())
    <nav>
        <ul class="pagination">
            {{-- Previous Page Link --}}
            @if ($paginator->onFirstPage())
                <li class="disabled" aria-disabled="true" aria-label="@lang('pagination.previous')">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&lsaquo;</span>
                </li>
            @else
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ $paginator->previousPageUrl() }}" rel="prev" aria-label="@lang('pagination.previous')">&lsaquo;</a>
                </li>
            @endif

            {{-- Pagination Elements --}}
            @foreach ($elements as $element)
                {{-- "Three Dots" Separator --}}
                @if (is_string($element))
                    <li class="disabled" aria-disabled="true"><span>{{ $element }}</span></li>
                @endif

                {{-- Array Of Links --}}
                @if (is_array($element))
                    @foreach ($element as $page => $url)
                        @if ($page == $paginator->currentPage())
                            <li class="active" aria-current="page"><span>{{ $page }}</span></li>
                        @else
                            <li><a href="{{ $url }}">{{ $page }}</a></li>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                @endif
            @endforeach

            {{-- Next Page Link --}}
            @if ($paginator->hasMorePages())
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ $paginator->nextPageUrl() }}" rel="next" aria-label="@lang('pagination.next')">&rsaquo;</a>
                </li>
            @else
                <li class="disabled" aria-disabled="true" aria-label="@lang('pagination.next')">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&rsaquo;</span>
                </li>
            @endif
        </ul>
    </nav>
@endif
```

Still if you want to use your own pagination view then its possible .First you need to register your custom view in Service Provider

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //defaultStringLength changed to 191 to support mysql below 5.7
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);



        Paginator::defaultView('custom-pagination');

        Paginator::defaultSimpleView('simple-pagination');

    }
}
```

so here in my example i have created two blade template called `custom-pagination.blade.php` and `simple-pagination.blade.php`

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#displaying-pagination-results

Answer (score 0):

if you have more pages use this template  same ==> datatable pagination )

```
@if ($paginator->hasPages())

    <div class="d-flex flex-sm-fill d-sm-flex align-items-sm-center justify-content-sm-between">
        <div>
            <p class="small text-muted">
                {!! __('Showing') !!}
                <span class="fw-semibold">{{ $paginator->firstItem() }}</span>
                {!! __('to') !!}
                <span class="fw-semibold">{{ $paginator->lastItem() }}</span>
                {!! __('of') !!}
                <span class="fw-semibold">{{ $paginator->total() }}</span>
                {!! __('results') !!}
            </p>
        </div>

        <div>
            <ul class="pagination">
                {{-- Previous Page Link --}}
                @if ($paginator->onFirstPage())
                    <li class="page-item disabled" aria-disabled="true" aria-label="@lang('pagination.previous')">
                        <span class="page-link" aria-hidden="true">@lang('pagination.previous')</span>
                    </li>
                @else
                    <li class="page-item">
                        <a class="page-link" href="{{ $paginator->previousPageUrl() }}" rel="prev"
                           aria-label="@lang('pagination.previous')">@lang('pagination.previous')</a>
                    </li>
                @endif

                {{-- Pagination Elements --}}
                @php
                    $currentPage = $paginator->currentPage();
                    $lastPage = $paginator->lastPage();
                    $pageRange = 4; // Number of pages to show before and after the current page
                    $ellipsis = '<li class="page-item disabled" aria-disabled="true"><span class="page-link">...</span></li>';
                @endphp
                @if ($lastPage <= 7) {{-- Show all page numbers --}}
                @for ($i = 1; $i <= $lastPage; $i++)
                    <li class="page-item {{ ($i == $currentPage) ? 'active' : '' }}"><a class="page-link" href="{{ $paginator->url($i) }}">{{ $i }}</a></li>
                @endfor
                @else {{-- Show ellipsis and range of pages around the current page --}}
                @if ($currentPage <= 4) {{-- First few pages --}}
                @for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++)
                    <li class="page-item {{ ($i == $currentPage) ? 'active' : '' }}"><a class="page-link" href="{{ $paginator->url($i) }}">{{ $i }}</a></li>
                @endfor
                {!! $ellipsis !!}
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="{{ $paginator->url($lastPage) }}">{{ $lastPage }}</a></li>
                @elseif ($currentPage >= $lastPage - 3) {{-- Last few pages --}}
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="{{ $paginator->url(1) }}">1</a></li>
                {!! $ellipsis !!}
                @for ($i = $lastPage - 4; $i <= $lastPage; $i++)
                    <li class="page-item {{ ($i == $currentPage) ? 'active' : '' }}"><a class="page-link" href="{{ $paginator->url($i) }}">{{ $i }}</a></li>
                @endfor
                @else {{-- Middle pages --}}
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="{{ $paginator->url(1) }}">1</a></li>
                {!! $ellipsis !!}
                @for ($i = $currentPage - 1; $i <= $currentPage + 1; $i++)
                    <li class="page-item {{ ($i == $currentPage) ? 'active' : '' }}"><a class="page-link" href="{{ $paginator->url($i) }}">{{ $i }}</a></li>
                @endfor
                {!! $ellipsis !!}
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="{{ $paginator->url($lastPage) }}">{{ $lastPage }}</a></li>
                @endif
                @endif
                {{-- Next Page Link --}}
                @if ($paginator->hasMorePages())
                    <li class="page-item">
                        <a class="page-link" href="{{ $paginator->nextPageUrl() }}" rel="next"
                           aria-label="@lang('pagination.next')">@lang('pagination.next')</a>
                    </li>
                @else
                    <li class="page-item disabled" aria-disabled="true" aria-label="@lang('pagination.next')">
                        <span class="page-link" aria-hidden="true">@lang('pagination.next')</span>
                    </li>
                @endif
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

@endif
```